# send and retrive in the model (select - dropDown) MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I like traffic and retrieve a select (dropdown) the MVC Model in C #?

my html

```
<select id = 'namePerson' name = 'namePerson'> 
     <option value = '@ idPerson'> @ namePerson </ option> 
</ select>
```

my controller

```
ViewBag.namePerson = mod.namePerson; 
ViewBag.idPerson = mod.idPerson;
```

By posting form is filled only IdPerson.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor()
```

By other hand, instead of using ViewBag, you could use

```
ViewData["namePerson"]
ViewDate["idPerson"]
```

And get your HTML like this

```
<select id = 'namePerson' name = 'namePerson'> 
    <option value = @ViewData["idPerson"]>@ViewData["namePerson"]</ option> 
</ select>
```

You only need to be sure that you're actually sending data and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! exactly what I needed. Truth. I will use good practice to use @ Html.DropDownListFor()